# Read Credentials by txt file and try login c#?

Tags: c#

I would create a loop for function and print message in catch for all logins failed and print "sucessful connected with...." for all good logins.
Now i tried with that code, but i get only one error in textbox of catch

Button1:

```
  if (openFileDialog1.FileName != string.Empty)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        string lineoflistemail;
                        while ((lineoflistemail = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            UserData d = new UserData();
                            string[] parts = lineoflistemail.Split(':');
                            count = parts.Length;
                            d.UserName = parts[0].Trim();
                            d.Password = parts[1].Trim();
                            data.Add(d);
                        }

                        foreach(UserData ud in data)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text += ("LOL" + ud.UserName + ud.Password + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
```

Second button code:

```
if (data.Count() == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Load user info first");
                return;
            }

            for( hola = 0; hola < data.Count(); hola++) 
            {


            var url = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
            var encoded = TextToBase64(data[0].UserName + ":" + data[1].Password);
            var myweb = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            myweb.Method = "POST";
            myweb.ContentLength = 0;
            myweb.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            var response = myweb.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            textBox1.Text += ("Connection established with");
            MessageBox.Show(hola.ToString());
        }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text += ("Error connection. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        }
```

Comment: And the error is......? This also looks like you're trying a bunch of username/password combos for emails. Sketchy.

Comment: I have a list with some list of random chars, just want to try, i know that i will got error but i want get it for all fake account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `try...catch` is outside of your `for` loop.  The first exception will exit the `for` loop, append the message to `textBox1`, then exit the button handler.

If you want to keep looping through even if there is an error, move the `try...catch` inside of the loop.  Here's an example:

```
for( hola = 0; hola < data.Count(); hola++) 
{
    var url = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
    var encoded = TextToBase64(data[0].UserName + ":" + data[1].Password);
    var myweb = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    myweb.Method = "POST";
    myweb.ContentLength = 0;
    myweb.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

    try
    {
        var response = myweb.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        textBox1.Text += ("Connection established with");
        MessageBox.Show(hola.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBox1.Text += ("Error connection. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: iT work all good... .thanks very much mate. Just a question, it should run like for successful login=?